# FontFamily on Shell -> TabBar -> Tab -> Title

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to set this a font family? I'm unable to find how to do it. In what way I can implement this?

[image]

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as i didn't find the direct property to set,here i use Custom Renderen to achive it (for Android):

create a **AndroidShell.cs** in Droid project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ShellTest.AppShell), typeof(AndroidShell))]
namespace ShellTest.Droid
{
  class AndroidShell : ShellRenderer
   { 
      public AndroidShell(Context context) : base(context)
       {
       }

      protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
      {
        return new MyBottomNavigationView(this);
      }
   }
}
```

create **MyBottomNavigationView.cs** :

```
internal class MyBottomNavigationView: IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    private AndroidShell androidShell;

    public MyBottomNavigationView(AndroidShell androidShell)
    {
        this.androidShell = androidShell;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {

        IMenu menu = bottomView.Menu;
        for (int i = 0; i < bottomView.Menu.Size(); i++)
        {
            IMenuItem menuItem = menu.GetItem(i);
            var title = menuItem.TitleFormatted;
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(MainActivity.Instance.Assets, "HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf");
            SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);

            sb.SetSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("",typeface), 0, sb.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            menuItem.SetTitle(sb);           
        }
    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
    }
}
```

create **CustomTypefaceSpan.cs**:

```
class CustomTypefaceSpan :TypefaceSpan
{
    private  Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) : base(family)
    {
        newType = type;
    }
    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds,newType);

    }
    public override void UpdateMeasureState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint,newType);
    }
    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf)
    {
        TypefaceStyle oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.Typeface;
        if (old == null)
        {
            oldStyle = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            oldStyle = old.Style;
        }

        TypefaceStyle fake = oldStyle & ~tf.Style;
        if ((fake & TypefaceStyle.Bold) != 0)
        {
            paint.FakeBoldText = true;
        }

        if ((fake & TypefaceStyle.Italic) != 0)
        {
            paint.TextSkewX = -0.25f;
        }

        paint.SetTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

and **HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf**  is put inside **Resources/Assets** with **BuildAction：AndroidAsset**

in **ios**,you could try add this in **AppDelegate.cs** :

```
 UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() {Font=UIFont.FromName("HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf",14), },UIControlState.Normal);
 UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf", 14), }, UIControlState.Selected);
```

HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf is put inside **Resources**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to set the code copy the code of the ResetAppearance method to the SetAppearance and it works. It clears the font color and the background color I set in the XAML. I supposed I need to set it on the Renderer. I'm right?

Comment: @GeorgeMR yes,you could use  `sb.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Android.Graphics.Color.Red), 0, sb.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);` to set color

Comment: Thanks Leo. You are great.

Comment: Is there a way to set the bottom navigation with a gradient background? I found the solution on Flutter, but I'm trying to set it in Xamarin.

Comment: @GeorgeMR if the answer is helpful，could you mark it，thanks

Comment: @GeorgeMR the bottom navigation you could try to use custom renderer

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Do you have sample app of this code? I am trying to make it work on iOS, couldn't do it so far.

Comment: Nice solution! For iOS, prefer to use the real font name instead of file name

Answer (score 2):

Leo Zhu's Answer is correct but didn't work for me until i put the `ResetAppearance(bottomView)` in `SetAppearance` Method. And i put this : `if (title == null) { continue; }` in `ResetAppearance` method.

At first, in your Android Folder, you need to add `internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }` to `MainActivity` Class in `MainActivity.cs` and Initialize it by `Instance = this;` in `OnCreate` method in the same class.

```
public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
{
    ResetAppearance(bottomView);
}


public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
{
   IMenu menu = bottomView.Menu;
   for (int i = 0; i < bottomView.Menu.Size(); i++)
   {
       IMenuItem menuItem = menu.GetItem(i);
       var title = menuItem.TitleFormatted;
       if (title == null) { continue; } 
       Typeface typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(MainActivity.Instance.Assets, "HYXuJingXingKaiW.ttf");
       SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
       sb.SetSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("",typeface), 0, sb.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
       menuItem.SetTitle(sb);           
   }
}
```