# Change default font of the application Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

I need to change the default font of the application, to change the font for Tabs and NavigationBar.

[image]

Comment: refer these links

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the title font in the NavigationBar, read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar), custom the `Shell.TitleView` in each contentPage:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="customTitle" FontSize="30"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

To change the tabbar title font, you need a custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
namespace App30.Droid
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {

        }

        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {

            IMenu menu = bottomView.Menu;
            for (int i = 0; i < bottomView.Menu.Size(); i++)
            {
                IMenuItem menuItem = menu.GetItem(i);
                var title = menuItem.TitleFormatted;
                SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);

                int a = sb.Length();
                
                //here I set fontsize 20
                sb.SetSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(20,true), 0, a, SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);

                menuItem.SetTitle(sb);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

A [sample project](https://github.com/XfHua/change-shell-font) has been uploaded here and you can check it.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack, this was useful, but I want to change FontFamily of tabs Not the size, I'm sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: @DeraDera Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046350/fontfamily-on-shell-tabbar-tab-title) may help.