# Xamarin Forms Shell - TabBar Android use custom font

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a Xamarin Forms Shell project with custom fonts added in .NET Standard project (Embedded Ressource) and exported like this :

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Ubuntu-Regular.ttf", Alias = "UbuntuRegular")]
[assembly: ExportFont("Ubuntu-Bold.ttf", Alias = "UbuntuBold")]
[assembly: ExportFont("Ubuntu-Italic.ttf", Alias = "UbuntuItalic")]
```

I'm using a TabBar in my shell and want to set font Ubuntu. I'm using custom renderer, for iOS it is eas, i just have to do

```
var normalTextAttributes = new UITextAttributes();
normalTextAttributes.Font = UIFont.FromName("Ubuntu-Regular", 10.0F);

uiTabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
```

in UpdateLayout method from my `IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker` inherited class. But how can we access theses fonts in Android, i tried something like

```
var title = menuItem.TitleFormatted;
var typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, "Ubuntu-Regular.ttf");
var sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);

sb.SetSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", typeface), 0, sb.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
menuItem.SetTitle(sb);
```

this solution is based from [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/185529/how-to-change-tabs-title-font-family). But it does not work.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/58046350 ?

Comment: Yes but we have to put font file into Android project as well, i was wondering if there was not a solution to get the font from .NET Standard project.

Comment: We have to implement this in custom renderer , and place the font file in each platform project . If possible could you provide a minimal ,basic project to test ? You can upload it on github .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT https://github.com/ArthurFSharp/AppShellTabBar it works when we include fonts in platform projects. I though there was a way to avoid this and get font from .NET standard project.

Comment: I don't think we can get the font from forms project in this way .